# min max and rounding hex in javascript

Tags: javascript, hex, rounding

I read the below post but that isn't exact my question or answer to my question: [Hexadecimal Floating-Point,roundIng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738665/hexadecimal-floating-point-rounding)

Given a floating point number, how do I round it off to the nearest whole hex number and then clam it between o and FF in javascript? For example, after converted to hex:

```
1e.fffffffffffe -> 1f
1e.111111111111 -> 1e
ff.fffffffffffe -> ff
-0.111111111111 -> 00
```

**Edit**
I came up with some half baked function, anyone cares to improve it?

```
function roundDblDigitHex(x) {
    x = Math.round(x);
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    if (x > 255) x = 255;
    x = x.toString(16);
    if (x.length === 1) x = '0'+x;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your solution (in the end, I would also just use `Math.round()`). Here is my suggestion (a little bit shorter, but the same code):

```
function roundDblDigitHex(x) {
    x = Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(x), 0), 255);

    return ("0" + x.toString(16)).slice(-2);
}
```